# Installing SATA3 SSD in HDD or SATA Optical drive

Tags: ssd, performance, sata, dell-inspiron, optical-drive

I have Dell Inspiron 5458 and want to replace my storage with SSD. The HDD is 6Gbps SATA 3 interface which is perfect for my new 6Gbps SATA 3 SSD. But my question is will I get same performance/speed if I install the new SSD in the Optical Drive slot. The Optical Drive is SATA connected but not sure if 6Gbps and SATA3 SSD will work exactly same or there will be any difference in terms of speed?
Thanks

Comment: Check with HWiNFO if the 2nd SATA interface supports SATA 3.

Comment: Thanks. Checked it, unfortunately its 1.5Gbps

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing 1.5,3, or 6gbps doesn't matter for most hard drives as they can't reach that speed anyway.

Only modern hard drives can even reach 150mb/s and not even all of them.  Plus they have access times >9ms usually.

You can still benefit from lower access times of an SSD and you will max out the SATA interface regardless.  It definitely won't be as much as SATA 3 port.  Also hard drives slow down as you go from the outer most track to the inner most track, and SSDs don't.

Comment: just to be clear(er), virtually all consumer SATA SSD drives have a max speed lower than 1.5Gbps. The SATA spec is the max theoretical speed *of the SATA interface*. Any HDD or SSD that quotes the SATA interface speed is asserting *compatability* with the interface, not quoting the device speed